# ImportError при попытке установки модулей с помощью pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

При попытке установить какой-либо модуль через консоль операционной системы Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS на виртуальной машине VirtualBox с помощью модуля pip появляется ошибка ImportError.
***Пример:***

```
    pip install dm-sonnet
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
        from pip import main
    ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Подскажите, как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pipenv
```

Еще вот так возможно, если не от root.

```bsh
pip install --user dm-sonnet
```